# Making duplicate of folders/subfolders with their contents in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, file-sharing

Good day everyone ! If this question is not related here, please excuse me and let me know from where I can get an answer.

In the Google Drive, I want to copy a folder including it's subfolders (with each and every content in each and every subfolder) to a different location. From what I've found in Internet, I tried few times but it fails to copy the contents in the subfolders to the new location.

For eg., top management has shared folders (containing 100s of files) related to couple of years, in which I need to delete the older/not relevant files and replace them with new files.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You said _I tried few times but it fails_.  Would you please edit your question to describe EXACTLY what you have tried. Regarding the issue with "top management" folders and files, this (delete "older" files and "replace" with newer") sounds like a different issue altogether. I suggest that you raise this issue under a separate question. Would you also clarify whether you have permission to access the "top management" folders and files"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.